# Best Strategy for get results and a counted/filter list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

we're developing a jobs-search site and we'd like to present search result like infojobs does, i mean:

```
|more   |result
|filter |list
|with   |(abstract
|result |of job
|count  |request)
```

the critical part is the filter list with counter,
for example we need

```
developer (30)
 |-Java (20)
 |-C# (5)
 |-Ruby (5)
```

we're using ejb3, jpa on jboss7 (so hibernate + ecache under the hood)
jsf2 (mojarra) with jquery for the presentation layer

i'm wondering what's the best strategy to achieve this,
is affordable to load from db all the result and then populate the filter/count part?

i think is better to fetch the result we're going to show and then another query to get the filter/count part!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) for this. Makes it much easier for you with both search and filtering. I would not recommend that you take in the whole result set and filter afterwards, that will give you performance issues in the end.

Comment: Thank you, Marthin, for your hint.
Perhaps it is more convenient to use Apache Solr in order to loosely couple our web application and its indexing service. Franco